# Time series forecasting in orange

Tags: time-series, forecasting, orange

Is there a time series windowing operator in Orange. How do we forecast a time series data. can you sight any examples like stock predictions etc.,

Comment: Must the forecast be done with Orange?

Comment: i'm a GUI guy .. sadly

Comment: Me too, but I am not afraid of copy/pasting data from one GUI into an other GUI. If it need to remain in the same UI, I suggest to ask Orange directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Time_series addon from the widgets menu. Orange provides once click widgets for visualization and forecast but there is a drawback, in Yahoo finance widget was removed in the latest update.